# Swipe effect in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to create a swipe event using React. I do not want to use any external component or jquery.

The css is something like :

```
.outter{
  position:relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.inner{
  position: absolute;
  width: 1000%; 
  left: 50px;
}
.child{
  float: left;
  margin-right: 15px;
}
```

In the react component I'm trying to do something like :

```
class Test extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        left: 0
    }
  }

  handleSwipe(){
    this.setState({left: -350})
  }

  render(){
    return(
        <div className="outter">
            <div className="inner" style={{left: this.state.left}} onSwipe={this.handleSwipe.bind(this)}>
                 <div className="child"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" /></div>
                 <div className="child"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" /></div>
                 <div className="child"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" /></div>
                 <div className="child"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" /></div>
            </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

React.render(<Test />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

How can I recognize swipe event?

If I in my example instead of `onSwipe` add `onClick` it works, but how can I make the swipe effect?

Here is [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jwm6k66c/1293/).

Comment: If you really want to do it yourself, then you need to listen and handle mousedown + mousemove + mouseup events.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

You can add `onTouch` event handlers to your React components:

```
onTouchStart={touchStartEvent => this.handleTouchStart(touchStartEvent)}
onTouchMove={touchMoveEvent => this.handleTouchMove(touchMoveEvent)}
onTouchEnd={() => this.handleTouchEnd()}
```

You may also want to add event handlers for mouse events for cross-platform compatibility:

```
onMouseDown={mouseDownEvent => this.handleMouseDown(mouseDownEvent)}
onMouseMove={mouseMoveEvent => this.handleMouseMove(mouseMoveEvent)}
onMouseUp={() => this.handleMouseUp()}
onMouseLeave={() => this.handleMouseLeave()}
```

You have the right idea for updating the `left` property of state in an event handler, but if you want the swiping functionality to feel natural you'll need to track the position of the pointer (be it a mouse or a touch) by updating `left` using the event's `clientX` property.

To do this, you'll need to store the position of the first touch and set `left` equal to the change in the touch's location. For added realism, you can also keep track of the touch's velocity and continue animating the component after the touch is finished.

Here's a quick-n-dirty Codepen I made for swiping to remove items from a list:

https://codepen.io/swingthing/pen/ZBGBJb/

Comment: Just a note: `onTouchStart={touchStartEvent => this.handleTouchStart(touchStartEvent)}` is functionally equivalent to `onTouchStart={this.handleTouchStart}` but is somewhat less efficient, as it causes a new anonymous function to be defined every render.

Comment: Great answer and codepen. Strangely, when copying you, I end up with a much more laggy experience.

Comment: I wish everyones quick and dirty code read like yours sir. 

Comment: So basically onSwipe event does not exist for React, only for React-Native, we use onTouch to replace onSwipe.

Comment: @jake Hoffman
Firstly, thank you for this great piece of code art. I was wondering if you have code for handleMotionStart function i am unable to find its code in above codepen.
Thanks in advance

Comment: @Gaurav I think the function you are looking for should be same as the one to handle mouse up for the mouse events. I've used `this.handleStart(touchStartEvent.targetTouches[0].clientX)` and it works.

Answer (score 30):

I used solution from most popular answer as a foundation for build what I was needed. Maybe somebody need something like this.

Idea was to move my custom slider left and right on swipe effect.
If you want it to be more sensitive - adjust value 150 to 75.

```
const [touchStart, setTouchStart] = React.useState(0);
const [touchEnd, setTouchEnd] = React.useState(0);

function handleTouchStart(e) {
    setTouchStart(e.targetTouches[0].clientX);
}

function handleTouchMove(e) {
    setTouchEnd(e.targetTouches[0].clientX);
}

function handleTouchEnd() {
    if (touchStart - touchEnd > 150) {
        // do your stuff here for left swipe
        moveSliderRight();
    }

    if (touchStart - touchEnd < -150) {
        // do your stuff here for right swipe
        moveSliderLeft();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Might be for someone my solution will be also useful:

```js
export const useSwipe = ({left, right, up, down}: {left?: () => void; right?: () => void; up?: () => void; down?: () => void;}) => {
  const touchCoordsRef = useRef({touchStart: {x: 0, y: 0, time: Date.now()}});
  const fnsRef = useRef({up, down, left, right});
  fnsRef.current = {
    up,
    left,
    down,
    right,
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    const handleTouchStart = (e: TouchEvent) => {
      touchCoordsRef.current.touchStart.x = e.targetTouches[0].clientX;
      touchCoordsRef.current.touchStart.y = e.targetTouches[0].clientY;
      touchCoordsRef.current.touchStart.time = Date.now();
    };
    const handleTouchEnd = (e: TouchEvent) => {
      const threshold = 150;
      const swipeSpeed = 1; // sec;
      const touchEndX = e.changedTouches[0].clientX;
      const touchEndY = e.changedTouches[0].clientY;
      const touchStartX = touchCoordsRef.current.touchStart.x;
      const touchStartY = touchCoordsRef.current.touchStart.y;
      const elapsedTime = (Date.now() - touchCoordsRef.current.touchStart.time) / 1000;
      if(elapsedTime > swipeSpeed) {
        return;
      }
      const xDistance = touchStartX - touchEndX;
      const yDistance = touchStartY - touchEndY;

      if(Math.abs(xDistance) < threshold && Math.abs(yDistance) < threshold) {
        return;
      }

      if(Math.abs(xDistance) >= Math.abs(yDistance)) {
        xDistance > 0 ? fnsRef.current.right?.() : fnsRef.current.left?.();
      } else {
        yDistance > 0 ? fnsRef.current.down?.() : fnsRef.current.up?.();
      }
    };
    window.addEventListener('touchstart', handleTouchStart);
    window.addEventListener('touchend', handleTouchEnd);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('touchstart', handleTouchStart);
      window.removeEventListener('touchend', handleTouchEnd);
    };
  });
};
```

Comment: Very nice, although I think the invoking of `right()` and `left()` should be reversed. When moving from the right of the screen to the left, `xDistance` will be positive, and I'd call that a left swipe (pushing the screen left). I think swiping up/down is correct here though

Answer (score -5):

Just found a DOM event that could be useful. Add .ontouchend to your HTML tag to detect any swipe event originating from that tag.

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_touchend.asp - ref