# React select multiple elements on swipe?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, touch-event

I'm trying to select elements on swipe from right to left.
Working on the desktop with onPointerDown and onPointerUp but not working on mobile with touch events.

Comment: Check that answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/40475633/8163773

Comment: Note that [pointer events](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html#pointer-events)  are different to [touch events](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html#touch-events). A pointer event is meant to be a more generic mouse event which means touch events may not necessarily trigger them.