# Getting swipe feature in replacement for next and previous button

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How can I get a swipe feature instead of having to use buttons on computer/phone.

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-kslpl?file=/App.js:1349-1354) is an example of a next a previous button that should be changed to swiping right or left.

I also would like dots to indicate which track is visible.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Swipe effect in react js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40463173/swipe-effect-in-react-js)

Answer (score 1):

I was able to add an `onMouseDown` event handler that captures the position of the mouse when it is over the `<h4>` tag and then when the mouse moves (`onMouseMove`) it determines if the new x coordinates of the mouse are greater than or less than the original x coord. If it's greater, execute the `onClickNext()` function, proceeding to the next track. If it's less, then it executes `onClickPrev()`. After the swipe is completed it resets `oldX` to `null` thus ending the swiping event check.

```
 onMouseDown() {
    this.setState({
      oldX: event.clientX
    });
  }

  onMouseMove(){
    var newX = event.clientX;
    if (this.state.oldX) {
      if (newX > this.state.oldX) {
        this.onClickNext();
        this.setState({ oldX: null });
      } else if (newX < this.state.oldX) {
        this.onClickPrev();
        this.setState({ oldX: null });
      }
    }
  };
```

Here is the [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-g0jir?file=/App.js) with the code.

Comment: your code isnt doing anything in the codesandbox, I want it to have the dots below as well that indicate which page it's on when scrolling if you know what I mean

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by not doing anything. When you click on the track, and as your mouse is down you drag left or right it changes the track accordingly, executing the swipe behavior. The dots were not specified in OP.