# How to make rating stars for 2 different question in react?

Tags: reactjs, react-rating

I am creating a react app to rating questions. And I have tried rating stars with png image and it is working fine for 1 question. But when I add another question with that rating stars it's not working.

**This is what I tried**

[image: result]

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

import fullStarSrc from "../img/highlightedStar.png";
import emptyStarSrc from "../img/star.png";

class joinPage extends Component {
  rate = (event) => {
    const { id } = event.target;

    console.log("clicked: " + id);
    var i;

    for (i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
      if (i <= parseInt(id)) {
        document.getElementById(i).setAttribute("src", fullStarSrc);
      } else {
        document.getElementById(i).setAttribute("src", emptyStarSrc);
      }
    }
  };
  pro1 = (event) => {
    const { id } = event.target;

    console.log("clicked: " + id);
    var i;

    for (i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
      if (i <= parseInt(id)) {
        document.getElementById(i).setAttribute("src", fullStarSrc);
      } else {
        document.getElementById(i).setAttribute("src", emptyStarSrc);
      }
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <body>
        <p class="ques">How would you rate our Service?</p>
        <div id="rating0" class="1">
          <img onClick={this.rate} class="star" id="1" src={emptyStarSrc} />
          <img onClick={this.rate} class="star" id="2" src={emptyStarSrc} />
          <img onClick={this.rate} class="star" id="3" src={emptyStarSrc} />
          <img onClick={this.rate} class="star" id="4" src={emptyStarSrc} />
          <img onClick={this.rate} class="star" id="5" src={emptyStarSrc} />
        </div>
        <p class="ques">How would you rate the quality of food?</p>
        <div id="rating0" class="1">
          <img onClick={this.pro1} class="star" id="1" src={emptyStarSrc} />
          <img onClick={this.pro1} class="star" id="2" src={emptyStarSrc} />
          <img onClick={this.pro1} class="star" id="3" src={emptyStarSrc} />
          <img onClick={this.pro1} class="star" id="4" src={emptyStarSrc} />
          <img onClick={this.pro1} class="star" id="5" src={emptyStarSrc} />
        </div>
      </body>
    );
  }
}

export default joinPage;
```

**How can I fix this problem?**

Comment: Seems like the basic react features are missing in your implementation. You should almost never do DOM manipulation in react. Please read [React Lifecycle](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html), [Rendering lists in React](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html), [React JSX](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html)

Comment: @sidath I quickly created an example on how I'd do it. take a look if you want: https://codesandbox.io/s/rough-bird-cy4yy?file=/src/App.js

Comment: thank you so much. I appreciate your help.

Comment: I would strongly recommend refactoring your code into something like @Christian provided. You did get an answer, but I think this is showing you the _right_ way of doing it _wrong_.

Comment: yeah, it's true. but I need to use png to make the rating. I already fix my problem with the @Viet answer.

Comment: It shouldn't be hard to switch to use png in this example...

Comment: how can I do it? I'm new to react

Comment: Give me a sec, and I'll write an answer for this

Comment: @sidath Added an answer now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refactored code to use React hooks and state instead of mutating state, also adding the rating to a new component.

see the sandbox for demo https://codesandbox.io/s/rough-bird-cy4yy?file=/src/App.js:0-851

```js
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import unstar from "./star-unselected.png";
import star from "./star-selected.png";
import _ from "lodash";
import "./styles.css";

function RatingStars({ initRating, onRatingChanged }) {
  const [rating, setRating] = useState(initRating);

  useEffect(() => {
    // if prop changed, we want to reflect that.
    setRating(initRating);
  }, [initRating]);

  function changeRating(newRating) {
    setRating(newRating);
    onRatingChanged(newRating);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      {_.times(5, (index) => (
        <img
          alt="rating stars"
          src={rating >= index + 1 ? star : unstar}
          key={index}
          onClick={() => changeRating(index + 1)}
        />
      ))}{" "}
      <span>has {rating} of 5 stars</span>
    </div>
  );
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <RatingStars
        initRating={3}
        onRatingChanged={(newRating) => {
          console.log(
            `NEW RATING (${newRating}) DETECTED FOR 1.. SAVING TO DB`
          );
        }}
      />
      <RatingStars
        initRating={1}
        onRatingChanged={(newRating) => {
          console.log(
            `NEW RATING (${newRating}) DETECTED FOR 2.. SAVING TO DB`
          );
        }}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: In this case how we track each and every single rating star? That means when I rate the first one by 3 stars and the second one with 4 stars how can I save these things into the database?

Comment: You can add a function prop to the ratingStars for getting updates for it, I can modify the sandbox to reflect this

Comment: Could you please modify the code? It's really help me lot

Comment: Take a look at the sandbox demo now

Comment: That's a great job. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Do you know how to swipe between pages in react? that means when I visit the web page with mobile and I swipe to left it redirects to another page.

Comment: I'd look into this question https://stackoverflow.com/a/40475633/3010171 It addresses swiping..

Comment: ok, thank you so much, Christian Moen.  I'll check it. I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

because it has the same id. You just update id in the second rate is

```
<div id="rating0" class="1">
      <img onClick={this.pro1} class="star" id="6" src={emptyStarSrc} />
      <img onClick={this.pro1} class="star" id="7" src={emptyStarSrc} />
      <img onClick={this.pro1} class="star" id="8" src={emptyStarSrc} />
      <img onClick={this.pro1} class="star" id="9" src={emptyStarSrc} />
      <img onClick={this.pro1} class="star" id="10" src={emptyStarSrc} />
    </div>
```

and update `pro1`:

```
pro1 = (event) => {
    const { id } = event.target;

    console.log("clicked: " + id);
    var i;

    for (i = 6; i <= 10; i++) {
      if (i <= parseInt(id)) {
        document.getElementById(i).setAttribute("src", fullStarSrc);
      } else {
        document.getElementById(i).setAttribute("src", emptyStarSrc);
      }
    }
  };
```

Comment: hey Viet, do you know how to swipe between pages in react? that means when I visit the web page with mobile and I swipe to left it redirects to another page.